# Looking for an alternative to Pamela for Skype for podcast recordings

Tags: software-recommendation, podcast

I've been using the software Pamela for Skype for recording podcasts.  The newest versions of Skype no longer support 3rd party applications.  What is a good alternative going forward?  I was able to install an older version of Skype, but support for older versions of Skype will soon be discontinued.